# rails client side validation uniqueness for boolean value in mysql database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, boolean, client-side-validation

I'm using client_side_validation uniqueness for a column named 'user_name' with scope 'customer_id' and 'active'. I just want throw an error if the user name is already exists in the table only if the customer id is present and active column is true and allow if the user name if tha active column is false  Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :with_customer_id_and_active, where("customer_id IS NOT NULL AND active = 1")

  validates :check_uniq_only_with_customer_id_and_active

  def check_uniq_only_with_customer_id_and_active

    if with_customer_id_and_active.where(:user_name => name).count > 0
      errors.add(:user_name, "user name should be uniq for active users")
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response sir, but i'm using client side validation gem it does not executes any function, it only takes the validators class such as presence, uniqueness for the particular attribute. I have a doubt that, is mysql database boolean value "0" or "1" is checked correctly for "true" or "false" in the live validation process